# BaseActivity to implement Navigation Drawer and Toolbar in every activity

Tags: android, tabs, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I created a base activity and base layout to extend those to get same nav drawer and toolbar in all my activities. However, I want to add sliding tab layout in one of my activity. Should I create a new layout for this? Or is there a way I can add this sliding tab layout to my extended base activity dynamically?

activity_base.xml

```
<include android:id="@+id/app_bar" layout="@layout/app_bar"></include>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/itembackground"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the sliding tab in the `Fragment` which you are loading in the `FrameLayout`. The sliding tab can be achieved using a `ViewPager` and the `ActionBar.TabListener` interface. The `ViewPager` can hold the tab `Fragment`s in a `FragmentStateAdapter` and access them using `getChildFragmentManager()`. This way, there is no need to create a separate layout for the tabbed screen, just extend from `BaseActivity` and use a `Fragment` with tabs.

For more on this, see the [**Creating Swipe Views with Tabs**](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) example.